# Prestashop : out-of-ranges orders

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a question about the carriers.

Is that possible, in case of "out of range behavior", to "duplicate" the shipping fees ?

For instance, my carrier set the price according to weight ranges, but my higher range is currently 5-8 kg. So, if a customer orders 100 products of 1kg, the shipping fees stay the same as if he was ordering only 8 products of 1 kg.

I don't know if I made myself clear enough, but... Is there a solution, for my problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can set a price for products which are heavier than X kg

Answer (score 0):

You can set Price by Total Weight in the carrier configuration page.

Price by Total Weight should be calculated dependently to each products quantities.

So you can set different weight ranges for example from 0 to 15kg => 8€, from 15kg to 40kg => 12€ and over 40kg => 15€.

[Here is the official documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Carriers).

Answer (score 0):

I know I can add more ranges, but I asked about out-of-ranges product. eg : if the max range is 8kg and the client order 16kg, Prestashop would automatically calcul 2*the 8kg price.
But I searched and it seems it is not possible, so I think I'll find another solution